# How to delete Windows User Environment Variable from registry

Tags: python, windows, registry, environment-variables

With this simple setup I can create any User Environment variable in the registry:

```
import win32con
import win32gui
import _winreg as winreg

def set_environment_variable(variable, value, user_env=True):
    if user_env: reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    else: reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

    if '%' in value: var_type = winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ
    else: var_type = winreg.REG_SZ

    with reg_key:
        winreg.SetValueEx(reg_key, variable, 0, var_type, value)     
    win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 'Environment', win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000)
```

create a `MY_VARIABLE`:

```
set_environment_variable('MY_VARIABLE', 'MY_VALUE')
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Question: How do I delete just created `MY_VARIABLE`?

Comment: I would create .bat file and run it from python code, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like it to be handled in Python.

Comment: In that case: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) says that you can do it using `DeleteKey` method.

Comment: A @MaLiN2223 says, use the `winreg.DeleteValue(<key>, <name>)` function.

Comment: Please illustrate your answer using the example code posted in question. And please post it as the answer so it could be up-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set or remove an environment variable from the Windows registry with:

```
def set_environment_variable(variable, value, user_env=True):
    """
    Set/Remove Environment variable from windows registry.

    :param variable: Environment Variable Name
    :param value: Environment Variable Value (None to delete)
    :param user_env: if true set in user env instead of in system env
    :return: None
    """
    if user_env:
        # This is for the user's environment variables
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(
            winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            'Environment', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    else:
        # This is for the system environment variables
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(
            winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment',
            0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

    with reg_key:
        if value is None:
            winreg.DeleteValue(reg_key, variable)
        else:
            if '%' in value:
                var_type = winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ
            else:
                var_type = winreg.REG_SZ
            winreg.SetValueEx(reg_key, variable, 0, var_type, value)

    # notify about environment change
    win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(
        win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
        'Environment', win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000)
```

To set the environment variable:

```
set_environment_variable('MY_VARIABLE', 'MY_VALUE)
```

To remove the environment variable:

```
set_environment_variable('MY_VARIABLE', None)
```

You can import the `win32` libs with:

```
import win32con
import win32gui
try:
    import _winreg as winreg
except ImportError:
    # this has been renamed in python 3
    import winreg
```